# Create a new column in pandas dataframe with the unique records from another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I need to create another column with the Unique records from an existing column. Here is what I have done and the results are satisfactory. However for a table which has more than 2 million records it takes lot of time to process. I wish to find out if there is a faster way to achieve this.

**Code**:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'RecordSku':["JQUZJM", "JQUZJM", "RTSHQN", "HLDPJP", 
"HLDPJP", "UCJXWO", "JAOKYL", "JAOKYL", "IVEMZB", "NTHNOW", "JAIFQI", 
"JAIFQI", "KPMXBI", "SNAFIC", "RTSHQN", "FJRCAY", "NAYGXF", "PSJFEU", 
"MMBNMW", "MMBNMW", "MMBNMW", "MMBNMW", "ZWVPLB", "KDARIS", "KDARIS"]}) 

df['Unique'] ="" # Create a column to populate the unique status

for x in range(0,len(df)):
    df['Unique'].iloc[x] = df.iloc[0:x].RecordSku.str.count(df.RecordSku[x]).sum()

     if df['Unique'][x]==0:
        df['Unique'][x]=1
    else:
        df['Unique'][x]=0
```

**Output**:

```
    RecordSku  Unique
 ---------------------
 0     JQUZJM       1
 1     JQUZJM       0
 2     RTSHQN       1
 3     HLDPJP       1
 4     HLDPJP       0
 5     UCJXWO       1
 6     JAOKYL       1
 7     JAOKYL       0
 8     IVEMZB       1
 9     NTHNOW       1
 10    JAIFQI       1
 11    JAIFQI       0
 12    KPMXBI       1
 13    SNAFIC       1
 14    RTSHQN       0
 15    FJRCAY       1
 16    NAYGXF       1
 17    PSJFEU       1
 18    MMBNMW       1
 19    MMBNMW       0
 20    MMBNMW       0
 21    MMBNMW       0
 22    ZWVPLB       1
 23    KDARIS       1
 24    KDARIS       0
```

The output mentioned is exactly what I am looking for. All the first unique records should have 1 and the next time the record appears it should be 0.
I am just trying to find a more efficient way to handle this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pd.Series.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) to determine whether a value in a series is a duplicate. In this case, you want non-duplicated elements, i.e. negate via `~`, and conversion from `bool` to `int`.

```
df['Unique'] = (~df['RecordSku'].duplicated()).astype(int)
```

Comment: Wow, I marked as duplicate question so that the option for me to accept as a correct answer disappeared. But a big thank you for your help.

Comment: @Sanjoy, No problem. If the marked duplicate solves you problem, upvote there. You can still accept here if it doesn't (green tick on left), but only do this if the marked duplicate doesn't solve your problem.